# Need Get-ADUser to ehco out for user input

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to get Powerhsell to echo out for user input and query AD,  but am getting stuck right off the bat. When I run the code it simply returns no results with the variable. Also would like to be able to trim down the return to only a few Properties. If multiple users have similar names I will need to create a loop or something to work through the multiple accounts just have not got there yet. The goal of this is to be able to quickly view the necessary information about users on a help desk and eventually be able use it to do simple password resets and moving of objects. Very new at this and am very thankful for any advice or help. This site always dose me well. Thanks in advance.

```
$Firstname = Read-Host 'What is the users FirstName?'

$Lastname = Read-Host 'What is the users Lastname?'

Get-ADUser -Filter {(Name -Like "$Firstname*") -And (Surname -Like "$Lastname*")} -Properties LastLogondate LockedOut EmployeeID
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with the `-Filter` parameter on AD cmdlets. You can use a variable by itself, but not inside of a string inside the filter.

So you can do this instead:

```psh
$Firstname = Read-Host 'What is the users FirstName?'
$Firstname = "$Firstname*"

$Lastname = Read-Host 'What is the users Lastname?'
$Lastname = "$Lastname*"

Get-ADUser -Filter {(Name -Like $Firstname) -And (Surname -Like $Lastname)} -Properties LastLogondate LockedOut EmployeeID
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument to the `Properties` parameter is an array of strings, you need to separate those by comma:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {(Name -like "$Firstname*") -and (Surname -like "$Lastname*")} -Properties LastLogondate,LockedOut,EmployeeID
```